# How to show monthly wise data in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am working on a report management system. The function of this application is that some users will enter their office information every month and the admin will be able to see them. Now I want to show the user entered information monthly wise. Suppose the user generates data for the month of January and when the admin clicks in January he will see all the information for the month of January. I'm new so I don't know how to do it.

I have used this method but when I use it all the monthly data is coming but I want to bring the specific month data.

```
public function RentCertificate(){

$report = Report::distric()->status(1)->desk(15)->groupBy('month', 'fiscal_year')->get();

return view('adcr.report.rent_certificate', compact('report'));
}
```

This is exactly what my database looks like.

| column_one | month | fiscal_year | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1381238 | January | 2021-2022 | 1 |
| 4131813 | January | 2021-2022 | 2 |
| 5381313 | February | 2021-2022 | 3 |
| 8173123 | February | 2021-2022 | 2 |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get monthly wise data in laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72060288/how-to-get-monthly-wise-data-in-laravel)

Comment: This is the third time you have asked this question. That's not how to use Stack Overflow - this just creates clean-up work for volunteers.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the code below to filter by month.

Just change the `$date` variable.

```
$date = "2022-05-17 22:55:07";
$month = Carbon::parse($date)->format('m');
return Report::whereMonth('created_at', '=', $month)->get();
```

OR

```
return Report::whereMonth('created_at', '=', "01")->get(); // for January
return Report::whereMonth('created_at', '=', "02")->get(); // for February
```

Comment: How Can I make ```$date``` dynamic? Because I have many data which has different date

Comment: @John, you're going to do a filter, right? Have the user select the month. If it is January, the value will be 01. You can see the data for that month with the following query: 

Report::whereMonth('created_at', '=', "01")->get();